# Maven dependancy not taking latest version

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, build.gradle

I have a android library which is on maven central. In my app's build.gradle I have defined dependancy.

```
compile('com.x:y:2+')
```

But this is not taking latest version.
I have release 2 version, 2.0.1 and 2.0.2 but It's taking 2.0.1 always. Why this is happening. My assumption was that it will always take latest version available.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities, which could lead to such a situation. Either mavenCentral is not specified as a repository and gradle uses the newest version of a different maven repository. The other possibility would be that you have a transitive dependency in your build script, which uses the 2.0.1 version. You can learn more about the structure of your dependencies on the cli with the `gradle dependencies` command.

As you can see these 'this version and upwards' dependencies are likely cause problems and I would recommend to avoid such.